# Generate multiple text-box in rails on user's request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails form i want to get mobile/contact details of a user. It could be more than one. How can I add text boxes dynamically once the user clicks the "add more" button.

Comment: i just want to give you brief idea how to do this, place a div in form, append textbox to this div whenever user click add button, this can be done by Jquery append method, also please make you are setting a counter variable in javascript function, so there will be unique name for all textbox in the form, atlast get values from textboxes in controller side and save it on db!

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will need to do some javascript and some ruby code to get working .

First on click of Add More,you need to show a partial already hidden inside your view.If This needs to be dynamic,then you need to call an ajax and then load the partial in a predefined placeholder

for example:-

load partial in advance in our view and hide it first

```
<div id="user_contact_details" style="display:hidden;">
   <%= render(:partial => 'user/contact_details') %>
</div>

######Now,ON CLICK of the Add More button,show this hidden partial using js

##add more button
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" role="button" id="add_more">Add More</a>

$('#add_more').click(function(){

##toggle partial placeholder
$("#user_contact_details").toggle('slow');

})
```

...the same can be done using ajax,you can also load partial using some conditions such as if user has more than one contact details..then load another partial with different form than previous one...

**Although..this might not be the unique solution,but atleast you can have an idea of how it can done.**

Answer (score 0):

```
I did this for you in JSFIDDLE, please refer this from my JSFIDDLE.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Manoj_Menon/eyxt6kjh/